# Is there a way to automate XML playlist creation for files in an S3 bucket?

Tags: xml, amazon-s3, playlists, amazon-web-services

I'm working on an XML-based, non-Flash music player for a client. They want to be able to upload files to a bucket and stream MP3s back to their website.

I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically update the XML file every time a new file is added so the client doesn't need to mess about with XML. I've heard of a PHP script that can generate a new XML file on a web server, but is this even possible?